# Can the CamelCase Property Names in Model Validation error messages be fixed?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a Asp.net Core REST service. Take a model snippet:

```
{
   public string ItemType { get; set; }
}
```

That's following C# naming conventions, naturally, in JSON, we would name it "itemType". I've fixed that part by setting the internal Json.net to use the camel case name resolver. So that's all good.

However, if the model fails validation, I get an error message:

```
"**itemType**":[
    "The **ItemType** field is required."
]
```

Yes, its nitpicky :), but is there any generic way to get the names in the error message to be camel cased as well so they match the field name?

Comment: I haven't done Core, and I'm _thinking_ it may work in old ASP.NET, but try putting a `[Description]` attribute on the property with a "user friendly" name for it. I _think_ it used to use that, if one was present.

Comment: The correct tag for ASP.NET Core MVC is [tag:asp.net-core-mvc], not [tag:asp.net-mvc]

Answer (score 1):

Please check the second part from my answer which is related to your question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51371894/2514158

The main idea is to create a custom model validation in addition to the camel case config.

Answer (score 0):

In the startup.cs file you can set the json formatter case. By default it should be camel case but it doesn't seem to effect model validation. Under the ConfigureServices method add:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonFormatters(j => j.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
}
```