# CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver not Working after MapHttpRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to implement JSON camel casing in my .Net API project. In my start up class I add the following lines:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = 
    new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false;
```

As I understand it this is what is required to implement camel casing on all routes. However when I add the following this fails to work, the responses come back as Pascal Case:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "DefaultApi",
     "{controller}/{id}",
      new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
);
```

When I remove the above MapHttpRoute line and use Route attributes in the controllers instead camel casing works fine.

Has anyone any idea as to what is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

Before we answer, you should understand first that the camel case API response overriding **will NOT affect the Model Validation** (we will solve this problem at the end of answer).

**FOR YOUR QUESTION:**

You have to use the same **HttpConfiguration** variable so try to use this instead

```
// config is an HttpConfiguration object

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "API Default",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
     defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

**FOR THE MODEL VALIDATION:**

You have to create a base controller that all your other controllers should inherit from, then override the ModelStateDictionary by creating a new method that you have to use instead (ModelState is a read-only property) as below (1):

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    public ModelStateDictionary ModelStateAsCamelCase()
    {
        var newModelStateDictionary = new ModelStateDictionary();

        foreach (var element in ModelState)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element.Key))
            {
                var keys = element.Key.Split('.');
                List<string> camelKeys = new List<string>();
                foreach (var key in keys)
                {
                    camelKeys.Add(key.First().ToString().ToLowerInvariant() + key.Substring(1));
                }

                // You can (add a / change this) code if the returned key is not
                // composed from the ObjectName.Property, such as when it is 
                // composed from the property name

                var newKey = camelKeys.Aggregate((i, j) => i + "." + j);

                newModelStateDictionary.Add(newKey, element.Value);
            }
            else
                newModelStateDictionary.Add(element);
        }
        return newModelStateDictionary;
    }
}
```

this method will edit the model state dictionary string key to comply the camel convention

now inside your action, you can use this method instead of the default ModelState

```
......

if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return BadRequest(ModelStateAsCamelCase());

......
```

1- I have checked many answer related to solve the camelCase problem in modelState even in .net core but non has provided a default config solution. as they mentioned that the modelState will not get affected by the default config used in the first part from my answer

Comment: The problem with this, is that you need to call !ModelState.IsValid, so, no more automatic handling with [ApiController]

Comment: there is a better way using interceptors I will update an answer ASAP

Comment: Check https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7439#issuecomment-541625844 to check other solution